# How to set useReducer initial state using API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I'm new to React and trying to build an app with a cart feature where users can add robots to the cart. I'm using `Context API` to provide cart across the app and `useReducer` for states. The robots are being fetched from a server and load just fine. But I can't seem to find a way to set the initial state of the `reducer` using fetched products. The state always returns an empty array for robots. How to solve this?

```
const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [robots, setRobots] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/robots')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setRobots(data?.data))
    }, [])

    const initialState = {
        robots: [...robots],
        cart: []
    }
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default CartProvider;
```

Comment: Since the initial state value is fetched asynchronously you'll need to dispatch an action to set the `state` value. Can you share your `cartReducer` function and any related code like actions and action creators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the initial state value is fetched asynchronously you'll need to dispatch an action to set the `state` value.

Example:

```
const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ... other reducer cases ...

    case 'INITIALIZE_CART': 
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

CartProvider

```
const initialState = {
  robots: [],
  cart: []
};

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [robots, setRobots] = useState([]);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/robots')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'INITIALIZE_CART',
          payload: {
            ...initialState,
            robots: data?.data,
          }
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

It's common to also hold some state on the app initialization status. UI conditionally renders based on this state value.

Example:

```
const initialState = {
  initialized: false,
  robots: [],
  cart: []
};
```

...

```
const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ... other reducer cases ...

    case 'INITIALIZE_CART': 
      return {
        ...action.payload,
        initialized: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Quick question though - So, If I may. I can use the variable 'initialized' value for conditionally rendering a loading spinner of sorts in child components before data from API response load, right?

Comment: @NoobCoder Yes, you certainly could do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);
```

`useReducer` will not monitor changes to `initialState`, it will only consider its initial value. You can just dispatch an action to update the state once the data is fetched.

```
const initialState = {
    robots: [],
    cart: []
}

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/robots')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                // dispatch action to update the reducer state 
            })
    }, [])
    

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default CartProvider;
```

If the nested components don't work well until the state is populated then you can conditionally render `children`:

```
  return (<CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
          {state?.robots?.length > 0 && children}
        </CartContext.Provider>);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had only one option to choose an answer as the correct one. Shame! BTW, apart from the conditional rendering, everything worked. Condition on the context was causing errors.

Comment: No problem. What's the error?